# Countably infinite subsets of natural and real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

1. $ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{N},  x < 2^{20}$;
2. $ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{N},  x > 2^{20}$;
3. $ \{ x \} : x \in \mathbb{R},  x > 2$.

Are any of these sets countably infinite?

I would have said the first two sets are countably infinte, because any subset of  $\mathbb{N}$ is countably infinte. The third set is uncountably infinte because  $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable →  $\mathbb{R}^1$ is uncountable. Agreed?

Comment: It depends whether you include finite in countable.  I have seen countable taken as countably infinite some places.  Otherwise I agree.  Note that the powerset of $\Bbb N$ is not a subset of $\Bbb N$, so you could delete "except the..."

Comment: Set _1_ is finite, set _2_ is a bijective image of $\mathbb{N}$, while set _3_ is a bijective image of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @MattAllegro why don't you post a reply where you elaborate on the bijective image idea. I would give you the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first set is finite and contains $2^{20}$ elements, all the integers beetween $0$ and $2^{20}-1$.

The second one is the image of $\mathbb{N}$ under the bijection $f$ such that $f(n)=n+2^{20}$. For this reason is countable (as $\mathbb{N}$ is countable).

The third set is the image of $\mathbb{R}^+$ under the bijection $g$ such that $g(x)=x+2$. For this reason is not countable (as $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not countable).